# Display current users time who is in different country

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Is it possible with vanilla JS to display foreign user time with his timezone?

Example:

- **ME**: I am located in Prague (GMT+1)
- **USER**: Is located in New York (EDT)

Current time is `const localTime = 20:53 GMT+1`

Current USER time is `const userTime = 15:53 EDT` - this is what I want to display to me: `USER's time is 15:53 EDT`

When `USER` is logged in in the beginning. I store his timezone offset: `const tzOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` Which returns difference from UTC in minutes.

How to with vanilla js display `userTime` `15:53 EDT` using this `tzOffset`?

I have tried `DateTimeFormat` but `options.timezone` does not accept that tzOffset. And new Date has just `toLocaleString()`.

Is there any easy way?

Edit:

#### Maybe better example

I have chat and there is `me` and the `USER`. If I hover over the `USER` I want to display a tooltip with his time with his timezone. Only what I have on my client is `Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()`.

it is easy to add Hours to my current `new Date()` and get his time. But it is hard to display his timezone - `EDT, GMT+/-X` etc..

Comment: No. However you can parse the return from [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) which contains the local time as HH:mm:ss and offset as GMT±HHmm and *might* contain a timezone name or abbreviation in brackets.

Comment: The *offset* is useless, you need the *timezone name*. Then it's as simple as `new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: 'America/New_York'})`.